# How to add Pagination in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, pagination

I need to show one row per page.
this my contoller class code

```
public function showcontent($id)
{
    $story=storybook::find($id);
    $content=storycontent::where('titleid', $story['id'])->paginate(1);
    //return $content;
    return view('storyBook/viewStory',compact('story','content'));
}
```

this my view class code

```
 @foreach($content as $content)
            <?php $a=null; ?>
            <?php $b=null; ?>

                <?php $a=$content->file1; ?>
                <?php $b=$content->file2; ?>

            <table style="height: 330px;width: 680px;margin-top: 120px;margin-left: 50px">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 340px"><img src="/{{$a}}" alt="Mountain View" style="width:330px;height:300px;"></td>
                    <td style="width: 340px"><img src="/{{$b}}" alt="Mountain View" style="width:330px;height:300px;"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br>
        @endforeach
```

In here i get only 1st row, rest of the rows not visible..
I do not know how to add pagination.

Comment: Only one row per page??

Comment: I get more than one rows for $content..but i need to show one row per page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@foreach($content as $content)`

So first of all change the naming of vars for example:

```
@foreach($content as $entry)
    <table style="height: 330px;width: 680px;margin-top: 120px;margin-left: 50px">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 340px"><img src="/{{$entry->file1}}" alt="Mountain View" style="width:330px;height:300px;"></td>
            <td style="width: 340px"><img src="/{{$entry->file2}}" alt="Mountain View" style="width:330px;height:300px;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
@endforeach

$content->links()
```

As you can see I've added `$content->links()` after foreach loop. This is the method of `Paginator` that print out the pagination navigation.